# Как использовать when в vars?

Tags: ansible

Состоит задача в том, чтобы при запуске сценария указывать значение через `--extra-vars`, и в зависимости от это сценарий использовал ту переменную, которая соответствует значению.

Некий пример, который объясняет суть моей проблемы:

Запуск сценария:

`ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "ver=3"`

Файл, который содержит переменные:

```
ver_python: "3.6.4/bin/python3"
when: ver == "3"

ver_python: "2.7.14/bin/python"
when: ver == "2"
```

Ну и часть сценария:

```
  - name: Installing
      shell: sudo -u usertest -i /home/usertest/.venv/{{ ver_python}} /home/usertest/lib/project/src/manage.py  collectstatic --noinput
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`when` можно использовать только в задачах/ролях и т.п., но не в описании переменных.

Либо используйте словарь вида:

```
python_path:
  ver_3: '3.6.4/bin/python3'
  ver_2: '2.7.14/bin/python'
```

и в коде `{{ python_path['ver_'+ver] }}`;

Либо вставьте условие прямо в шаблон переменной – это ведь Jinja2:

```
python_path: >
  {{ '3.6.4/bin/python3'
  if ver | default(2) | int == 3
  else '2.7.14/bin/python' }}
```

и в коде уже прямо `{{ python_path }}`

Comment: Второй пример - как раз то,что нужно. Благодарю